# pandas: multi-x-axis to multi-y-axis plot using chart

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, plot, charts

I've a data-frame as below

```
    Period        Backed    Closed  Failed  Successful  total
0   2015_November   1   0   0   7   8
1   2015_December   0   0   0   30  30
2   2016_January    0   1   0   46  47
3   2016_February   0   0   2   72  74
4   2016_March      0   1   0   56  57
5   2016_April      1   0   0   52  53
6   2016_May        2   4   1   50  57
7   2016_June       2   2   2   102 108
8   2016_July       0   0   0   10  10
10  Grand_total     6   8   5   425 444
```

I can plot it fine using `Period` for `x-axis` and `Backed`,`Closed`,`Failed`,`Successful` for Y axis using following code.

```
# Create a chart object.
chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'column'})

# Configure the series of the chart from the dataframe data.
for col_num in range(2, len(df3.columns) ):
    chart.add_series({
        'name':       ['modified_data', 0, col_num],
        'categories': ['modified_data', 1, 1, (len(df3.index) - 1 ), 1], # rows , columns
        'values':     ['modified_data', 1, col_num, (len(df3.index) - 1 ), col_num],
        'fill':       {'color': brews['Spectral'][col_num - 1]},
        'gap':        200,
    })

# Insert the chart into the worksheet.
ws2.insert_chart('B14', chart)
```

Here is Graph:

[image]

However, I've requirement to separate  `Period` into `Year` and '`Month` and then use both as on x axis to plot against `Backed    Closed  Failed  Successful  total` in y axis.
I separated them into new data-frame as below.

```
    Year    Start_Month Backed  Closed  Failed  Successful  total
0   2015    November    1   0   0   7   8
1   2015    December    0   0   0   30  30
2   2016    January     0   1   0   46  47
3   2016    February    0   0   2   72  74
4   2016    March       0   1   0   56  57
5   2016    April       1   0   0   52  53
6   2016    May         2   4   1   50  57
7   2016    June        2   2   2   102 108
8   2016    July        0   0   0   10  10
10  Grand   Total       6   8   5   425 444
```

However I'm unable to find a solution for multi-x-axis to multi-y-axis plot using `charts` that will generate plot same as above.
Can we combine `Year and  Start_Month` and use that as `x-axis` only for plotting purpose? While on excel-data it would still show as two separate columns.

Any pointers are welcome.